# How can I stop Google photos to show images from my google drive

Tags: photos, lg, google-drive

So I have some private images that I would rather not like to show up on google photos, I have them on my google drive but today I wanted to show some pictures of my office to a friend of mine when some other pics showed up that I uploaded on drive the day before,

Is there anyway to hide those images from google photos?

Answer (score 1):

You may choose to show or not *all* images from Drive to Google Photo, not individual one. There's a **Google Drive** setting in Photo for that.

There's also an analogue setting in Drive, to show images from Photo. You may turn off the setting in Photo and turn on the Drive one, so you may upload images in Drive if you want to not show it in Photo or upload them in Photo to show them also in Drive.